# How to do a transaction using rpc with python?

Tags: nodeos, eosio.token, python

I am trying to make a transaction on eos.
I have a node running on docker and created an account with cleos.

I tried following this:
https://github.com/EOSBlock/EOS-Tutorials/blob/master/EN/transfer-tokens-using-RPC.md

But it gives me this when creating the contract:

> no wasm file found
>   /opt/eosio/bin/data-dir/contracts/eosio.token/eosio.token.wasm

I also tried some python libraries, but the problem there was that the contract eosio.token is missing, so I guess it's in the end the same problem as above.

Generally I am also confused why the eosio.token is not already existing in the testnet. In my understanding it is not a private testnet then why isn't the eosio account and contract already there?

Comment: why do you think you're not a private testnet? did you provide your `nodeos` with the `genesis.json` for the public testnet you wanted to connect to?

Comment: I followed more or less this https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart. It doesn't explicitly say it but I assumed its not private as there are already a lot of blocks present

Comment: ah, that article guides you to start your own chain from scratch; it's not connecting to a public chain. you'd need to push the `eosio.*` contracts to enable the various functionalities

Comment: ok, makes sense. so if the node is running it just produces empty blocks even though there are no transactions or anything going on?

Comment: yeah that's right

Comment: Do you know how I would sign a transaction locally?
Using the jungle testnet I can make use of the commited smart token contract, but there seems to be no endpoint of nodeos or cleos to sign a transaction, except for the command line, which is not very useful in my case.

Comment: i believe that may be an appropriate separate question to ask to avoid unrelated discussions in comments

Comment: you are right of course